# What is wrong with cyrillic package?

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic

I downloaded `cyrillic` package and installed it into `/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/cyrillic`. I did `latex cyrlatex.ins`, and then `texhash`. Now this is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
This text is in Russian: проверка.
\end{document}
```

This is what I see:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live/MacPorts 2009_6)
entering extended mode
(./x.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1000
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live/MacPorts 2009_6)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1000
! I can't find file `larm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: larm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?
```

What this all is about? What is missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This installation solved the problem:

```
sudo port install texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-fonts-extra
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`LH fonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lh) package needs to be installed. It contains the missing file `larm1000.mf` from which mktextfm produces `larm1000.tfm`. Without that, LaTeX claims that the font cannot be loaded.

The `LH` package may be installed using tlmgr, which is the TeX Live package manager, or in your case by choosing an OS distribution package (also common on Linux) which bundles this and further font packages. As seen in the [MacPorts TeX Live packages list](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages), `texlive-lang-cyrillic` is the required package.