# Cyrillic on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: fonts

### Background

I'm using Ubuntu Precise with the standard repository packages rather than a manually installed TeXLive. I'm trying to include some Cyrillic in the bibliography of a paper which I'm compiling with `pdflatex`, following the [advice of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72690/48314) that the best option is to use

```tex
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

But even a very simple test case

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Testing \foreignlanguage{russian}{Обмен шифрами}
\end{document}
```

gives errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./minimum.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>

  <snip>

kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1000
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000
/usr/bin/mktextfm: 96: /usr/bin/mktextfm: mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000: not found
grep: larm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.8 ...anguage{russian}{Обмен шифрами}
```

I think the only relevant extra information from `minimum.log` is

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T2A+cmr on input line 7.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
```

### Extra details

I don't understand all the levels of indirection, but in an attempt to track them down I ran

```
$ grep -rE "\blarm([^0-9]|1000)" /usr/share/tex* 2>/dev/null
Binary file /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb matches
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-minimal-t2a.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/scripts/pkfix/pkfix.pl:#       same type 1 font, eg. (ecrm1000, larm1000) -> SFRM1000.
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd:\EC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{n}{larm}
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/doc/fonts/lh/fonttest/allenc0.tex:\FontPage {larm1000}
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/doc/fonts/lh/fonttest/allenc2.tex:\FontPage {larm1000}
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/doc/generic/t2/examples/example2.tex:\font\larm=larm1000    % Set the default font --- Cyrillic
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/doc/generic/t2/examples/example2.tex:\larm                  % T2A encoded Computer Modern font.
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_t1.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map:larm            lh              lh-t2a
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_ndl14.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_dl14.map:larm1000 SFRM1000 "T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap/dvipdfm_dl14.map:larm1000 cm-super-t2a sfrm1000 -r
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap/dvipdfm_ndl14.map:larm1000 cm-super-t2a sfrm1000 -r
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap/dvipdfm.map:larm1000 cm-super-t2a sfrm1000 -r
```

I have `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb` and `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc` from Ubuntu package `cm-super-minimal`, so I think that I have the source files and am just missing some files to tie it all together.

### Question

I'm not too fussed about fixing the underlying problem - it's a bit late to propose a patch for Precise, because it's in support mode now. But how can I obtain or generate the files which I'm missing, and get my document to compile and display the Cyrillic text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might like to have a look at our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get more information about out site.

Comment: I suspect a problem with write permissions for the `~/.texmf-var` directory.

Comment: @egreg, it certainly looks like a permissions issue, but it's not with `~/.texmf-var` because if I run `mf` manually it writes to `~/.texmf-var` without problem.

Comment: I think you need to determine what the user and or group of the created `mf` process is.  It is that process that needs correct persmissions to write to `~/.texmf-var`

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh, this is not TeXlive, but ubuntu's... did you read this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5101/36131 ?

Comment: @doed, I did read that answer, and it wasn't the problem. I actually found a workaround which allowed me to generate the missing file and I have successfully compiled my document, although for reasons I don't understand the high-rep users here seem to think that my solution belongs in the question rather than in an answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor but you can always provide an answer, even if it doesn't get a vote, but perhaps someone later on, might find it useful. If that was the workaround, which worked for you, and it's not a comment...you should write an answer. I didn't follow the question, since you first posted it, but I don't think that neither Swann nor egreg would have an opinion against it, and whether it belongs to a comment or answer. Perhaps other high-rep users would, but not those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdflatex` is actually trying to create the missing files, but there's some permissions issue. I don't know how to fix the real problem, but there are two workarounds which will allow you to compile your document.

### The clue

The error messages talk about `mktextfm larm1000`. If you try to run that command directly from the shell, you get the same errors:

```
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000
/usr/bin/mktextfm: 96: /usr/bin/mktextfm: mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000: not found
grep: larm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
```

### Workaround 1

If you `sudo` it, it will succeed, *even though* the files which it writes are in `~/.texmf-var` and it shouldn't obviously need any privileges beyond those which you have.

### Workaround 2

The error messages also show that `mktextfm` is trying to run

```
mf-nowin -progname=mf "\mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000"
```

You can run that without `sudo`; it will create `~/.texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/larm1000.mf` as well as `./larm1000.600gf`, `./larm1000.log`, and `./larm1000.tfm`. `pdflatex` will now compile your document. However, it's a good idea to

```
mv ./larm1000.tfm ~/.texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a/
```

because otherwise you may run into the same problem in future if you try to compile documents with Cyrillic from a different working directory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks more like an addition to you question rather than an "Answer". Please edit your question instead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I'm not sure why you think that. The question sets out a problem (with perhaps a bit more detail than necessary, but it might help people find it with Google); this answer offers two solutions with a brief explanation and discussion of which is best.

Comment: I don't understand your answer then.  What you do you mean by "glue"? It has a pretty specific meaning in the tex, but does not make sense here.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I'm using it in the [generic sense](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/glue.html) of "something which connects things": in this case the config file which links together the font files included in the relevant Ubuntu packages.

Comment: OK, but confusing.  However your "answer" still sounds like a step on the process to diagnosing the problem, rather than a solution.

Comment: In my case, I needed to install the TeXLive `lh` package, as answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5101/38471.