# Using cyrillic with Tex Gyre Pagella and pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, cyrillic

I just saw in this posting: [How to access cyrillic letters in the TeX Gyre fonts (e.g. pagella)? - comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.text.tex/vto7d4zkVzA#!topic/comp.text.tex/vto7d4zkVzA) the note: "the TeX Gyre Pagella font, which includes glyphs
for cyrillic.". There is an MWE there, which apparently worked in 2009; here it is (I just moved the `fontenc` line before the `babel` line, because `pdflatex` complained):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} % before babel!
\usepackage[ngerman,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

Добро пожаловать!

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

Some german umlauts: ÄÖÜ, äöü, ß

\end{document}
```

I build this with `pdflatex test.tex`, and it fails on Texlive 2014 with:

```
...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1000
! I can't find file `larm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: larm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?
```

Apparently I may be missing some package, but I have no idea which one.

Is it possible to get this example working with `pdflatex`, and if so - how?

---

EDIT: Just found [What is wrong with cyrillic package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5088/what-is-wrong-with-cyrillic-package), and so I managed to fix the problem by installing the TexLive `lh` package, then I got the document to compile:

```bash
tlmgr install lh                      # passes, font not really tgpagella?
tlmgr install collection-langcyrillic # installs 36 packages, like babel-bulgarian,... lcyw, lhcyr...
```

With that, the output is:

[image: test.png]

... and the cyrillic font doesn't look like `tgpagella`. So I installed `collection-langcyrillic`, but that didn't change the output either; still getting in the transcipt:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/qpl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.
```

... so apparently, the output shows the cyrillic of "Computer Modern". Now, if just the cyrillic font could be made like `tgpagella`, that would be great...

Comment: You need `cm-super` for this to work. It compiles fine here although it does not use TG Pagella for the Cyrillic. There is no font definition for `T2A` for any of the TeX Gyre fonts, (Nor is there for `T2C` which is used in the code you linked to.) If XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX is an option, you could use the opentype version which seems to support Cyrillic.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @cfr - it turns out I had `cm-super` installed already, what I was missing was `lh` (made an edit to OP). You're right, seemingly there is no `T2A`/`T2C` in `tgpagella` - thanks for the tip on the opentype version, will look it up. Cheers!

Comment: I can't get it to work with the opentype but I'm not very good with either `fontspec` or Cyrillic, so this does not mean very much!

Comment: As far as I know, the TeX Gyre fonts have never supported Cyrillic. They have some Greek characters in the OpenType version.

Comment: @egreg `otfinfo -s` lists Cyrillic script... but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @cfr Neither am I; I guess some part of the workflow adds it to the font under some circumstances. I consider it a bug.

Comment: If you have MS Office there should be Palatino Linotype font in you system, it has greek and cyrillic. I'm not sure, but maybe there is a free version of MS Office just for viewing documents, but no editing. In addition, if you are on OS X there is Palatino font, but it seems to lack small caps.

Answer (score 5):

Right, as @egreg and @cfr pointed out, there is no Tex Gyre Pagella in cyrillic; looking a bit further, I found:

- [latex - Cyrillic in Palatino-like font - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358648/cyrillic-in-palatino-like-font)

> Your choice may depend on what you mean by Palatino-like and whether and how much you're willing to pay for a commercial font. The open source Linux Libertine font is a serif font that has Cyrillic glyphs, but it's not really Palatino-like

- [Using cyrillic and palatino together? - comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.text.tex/hkiPzlm5hZE#!topic/comp.text.tex/hkiPzlm5hZE)

> I now get the whole palatino family (including \em, \sc, etc.) for Roman letters. ...  But none of the font attribute commands do anything for Cyrillic text.

... and if that wasn't enough, here is what I get for `fontforge /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf`:

[image: fontforge.png]

... which confirms that the font indeed has some Greek characters, but no Cyrillic ones.

So I was about to drop all this, when I found [CTAN: substitutefont](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/substitutefont), which notes:

> Combine font families [...]
>   Tests/Examples  [...]
>   * Times/Helvetica/Courier (TeX Gyre) with Cyrillic ParaType_ fonts: `<cyrillic-paratype.tex>`__, `<cyrillic-paratype.pdf>`__

... and as I read in [cyrillic-paratype.tex](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/substitutefont/cyrillic-paratype.tex), seemingly `paratype` works as a cyrillic substitute for `palatino`/Tex Gyre Pagella - and it actually looks good enough for me (not exactly the same, but certainly doesn't poke the eyes as much, as when it was Computer Modern cyrillic there):

[image: test.png]

Here is the MWE that produces that output - I simply load `paratype` before `tgpagella`, and after `tgpagella` is loaded, I use `substitutefont` to set paratype as the default "roman" when T2A encoding is used:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} % before babel!
\usepackage[ngerman,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{paratype} % tlmgr install paratype
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}

\begin{document}

Добро пожаловать!

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

Some german umlauts: ÄÖÜ, äöü, ß

\end{document}
```