# Using PTSerif-TLF for Cyrillic with TeX Gyre Pagella

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, tex-gyre-math

I want to include some Cyrillic with a TeX Gyre Pagella text and math font document. I'm using TeXLive 2019.

As indicated in [Using cyrillic with Tex Gyre Pagella and pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215447/using-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella-and-pdflatex), running `pdflatex` on the following source works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

The topologist is {\Russian Алекс\'{а}ндров}.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

**However**, running `xelatex` on the following surce produces output from which the indicated Cyrillic just disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % load here to avoid \dddot clash
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{paratype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{substitutefont}%
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}% 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

The topologist is {\Russian Алекс\'{а}ндров}.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

**Question**: How should this second source be fixed so as to allow the Cyrillic to appear, too?

(I did put `Map paratype-truetype.map` into my local `updmap.cfg` file and did run `updmap-user`.)

Comment: do not use legacy 8-bit encodings such as T2A and T1 with xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So if I use `pdflatex` instead, and therefore omit `\usepackage{fontspec}`, what do I do instead of the `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` commands?

Comment: Or, in the alternative, if I do want to use xelatex, what do I do about encodings with `babel` and `PTSerif-TLF`?

Comment: You would load the `tgpagella` package and not load `fontspec`. However, I recommend using modern Unicode fonts if you can.  (Pagella is a clone of Palatino, and the real deal has Cyrillic letters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using XeTeX or LuaTex you should use other ways of switching fonts. One nice way is offered by `babel` with its `\babelfont` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % load here to avoid \dddot clash
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{PT Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

The topologist is {\Russian Алекс\'{а}ндров}.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also note that TeX Gyre Pagella is a clone of Palatino, and the authentic Palatino Linotype has Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 6):

XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX use a completely different paradigm for fonts, because *everything* is available in a single output encoding, namely `TU`. Thus `substitutefont` does nothing sensible here.

You could use `\babelfont` as suggested in the other answer, but you will get several spurious warnings: support for fonts in `babel` is still in development.

With `polyglossia`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{PT Serif}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

The topologist is \foreignlanguage{russian}{Алекс\'{а}ндров}.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments also for \blindmathpaper :-) that I not knew.

Comment: @Sebastiano `\blindmathpaper` comes from `blindtext`. It was in the code from the OP.

Comment: State exams blurred my eyesight :-). Congratulations the same. :-)

Comment: This works just fine, too. (I prefer the answer using `babel` instead of `polyglossia` simply because, if I make different font family choices for my project, things are already set up for pdfLaTeX rather than for XeLaTeX. I may change my mind!)