# Use a greek personal font as a second font, the first one is the classic tex one

Tags: fonts, greek

I need to write a tex file in french.
But in this tex file, there will be also many characters in greek and I want to use a personal font for these ones.
How could I do ?

Comment: Are you using a modem setup with fontspec and LuaTeX/XeTeX or a classical setup with pdftex?

Comment: XeLateX seems to be good for the project isn't ? So I went on it. So I use fontspec.

Comment: Have a look at the answers for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498120/140850.

Comment: Yes it works thanks a lot !