# Heavier cyrillic font with ScholaX?

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

The Cyrillic font with the ScholaX roman text font seems too light.

- Which Cyrillic font would be a better match?
- Exactly how to I specify its use along with ScholaX and for `pdflatex` (*not* `xelatex`!)?

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,main=english]{babel}
\babeltags{ru = russian, fr = french, de = ngerman, po = polish}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[scale=0.93,theoremfont]{scholax}

\begin{document}

The topologists are Moore, \textde{M\"{o}bius}, \textfr{Poincar\'{e}}, 
and {\Russian Алекс\'{а}ндров}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Too-light Cyrillic with ScholaX]

Comment: I just remembered how to do it: `\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}`. Other posts have covered this method, so probably this question should be deleted.

Comment: A first step would be to suggest this question as a duplicate of these other Q&A. Duplicate questions marked as such are a good thing, since they increase the chance that people find the best answers.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215447/using-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella-and-pdflatex. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498120/using-ptserif-tlf-for-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using cyrillic with Tex Gyre Pagella and pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215447/using-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella-and-pdflatex)

Comment: @RalfStubner: The link you supply is the same one I included in my previous comment.

Comment: I know. This is what happens when one initiated the process to get a question marked as duplicate.