# TeXstudio code working on Windows 10 but not on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu, font-encodings, cyrillic

Right now I'm using TeXstudio (2.10.8) to create sheets with vocabulary for learning both Germand and Russian (despite I'm studying physics and that's the main point of using LaTeX). I've created a couple of templates to make it easier to create a new document of this kind. This is the preamble used for the German documents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{longtable}
%
\author{}
\title{\textbf{DIE VERBEN} - os verbos}
\date{}
%
```

For which I get two errors.

1. With **\maketitle** highlighted:

   *Font T1/cmr/m/n/20.74=ecrm2074 at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \maketitle*

And a few other of the same kind.

2. Referencing to a **fontenc.syn** file:

   *Font T1/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont*

I go to that file and I find this message:

```
\DeclareOption*{%
 \let\encodingdefault\CurrentOption
 \edef\reserved@f{%
  \lowercase{\def\noexpand\reserved@f{\CurrentOption enc.def}}}%
 \reserved@f
 \InputIfFileExists\reserved@f
      {}{\PackageError{fontenc}%
       {Encoding file `\reserved@f' not found.%
        \MessageBreak
         You might have misspelt the name of the encoding}%
       {Necessary code for this encoding was not
       loaded.\MessageBreak
       Thus calling the encoding later on will
       produce further error messages.}}%
 \let\reserved@f\relax
 \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\CurrentOption}%
                             {T2A,T2B,T2C,X2,LCY,OT2}%
 \ifin@
    \expandafter\in@\expandafter\cyra\expandafter
                            {\@uclclist}%
    \ifin@
    \else
      \update@uclc@with@cyrillic
    \fi
 \fi
}
\ProcessOptions*
\fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

Where it says

```
        \expandafter\in@\expandafter\cyra\expandafter
```

**\cyra** is highlighted. It may be making reference to the code for cyrillic alphabet, which I'm not using on this document as you can see on the header (onlt T1 font is used).

The line reference for the error is where it says

```
\fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

Now, the preamble I'm using for the Russian sheets is pretty much the same, except for the font pack OT2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
%
\newcommand\textcyr[1]{{\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont #1}}
%
\author{}
\title{Vocabulario ruso}
\date{}
%
```

In this case I get an error message for every single line. Some of then are of the same kind as in the German case

```
*Font T1/cmr/m/n/20.74=ecrm2074 at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \maketitle*
```

And, above all, of this kind

```
*Encoding scheme `OT2' unknown. \textbf{\textcyr{termo ruso}}*
```

In the **fontenc.syn** file I get the same message as before, but with two lines higlighted instead of one

```
\ProcessOptions*
\fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

---

As I mention on the title, this documents work perfectly fine when I'm runing Windows, but crash when I try to operate with them in Ubuntu 16.04. I made some reaserch on the web and found different theories, but none of them seem to work in my case.

I'm sorry if the message is too long, just wanted to be as clear as posible.

Comment: I suppose that you are using TeXlive. Try to install some font packages. For example, `sudo apt-get install` and choose some
`texlive-fonts-extra`  or      `texlive-font-utils` or
`texlive-fonts-recommended`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Sigur. With your help I solved the problem with the German documents, and with this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5088/what-is-wrong-with-cyrillic-package) I solved the problem with the cyrillic package. You both saved my day.